# How can I lay out multiple choice answers as a matrix with exam?

Tags: exam

For creating a test I use the `exam` class, which worked out fine so far.
Now I need to implement a question with the possible answers beeing a matrix like this:

[image: Matrix]

However I can't manage to put the `\choice` command (of the `exam` class) in that form (I want to use `exam` for printing automatic solution papers also). When I simply put it inside a tabular it does not seem to work out. How could I realize this?

PS:
The example above (just as a visual explanation, it is not using the `exam` class) is:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
    \begin{tabular}{r|ccc}
     & Orange & Green & Aubergine \\
     \hline
     Fruit & $\Box$ & $\Box$ & $\Box$ \\
     Vegetable & $\Box$ & $\Box$ & $\Box$ \\
     Colorname & $\Box$ & $\Box$ & $\Box$ \\
    \end{tabular}\
\end{document}
```

[Edit: add example code]
[Edit2: Clarify question]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: I would have, but I didn't have the slightest idea, what kind of example would be helpful for that kind of question...

Comment: @HarishKumar Do you think the source of the above would be helpful?

Comment: Certainly. It will save us some typing (atleast).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `exam` documentation states:

> The `checkboxes` environment creates a list environment with the
>   choices as the items in the list.

So every `\begin{checkboxes}...\end{checkboxes}` creates a new list. You can't put different items from the same list in different cells in a table. So you'll need to create a new one-item list for every cell in your table. And you can't put a list in a tabular without having a predefined column width. So either use alignment options (`p`, `m`, `b`, ...) that give you a fixed column width or put the list in a `minipage`-like environment such as `varwidth` (which will also horizontally center its content).

As our lists are one-item lists and we don't really want them to look like a list, we'll need some customization. In the exam class this is done width `\checkboxeshook`. So go for:

```
\renewcommand{\checkboxeshook}{
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
}
```

Now make a macro so you don't need to copy paste too much code. This will also increase the readability of your code. Here are 2 macros. One for a regular checkbox option and one for the correct choice checkbox:

```
\newcommand{\tablechoice}{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\begin{checkboxes}\choice\end{checkboxes}\end{varwidth}}
\newcommand{\tablecorrectchoice}{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\begin{checkboxes}\CorrectChoice\ \end{checkboxes}\end{varwidth}}
```

All these things put together get you:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}

\newcommand{\tablechoice}{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\begin{checkboxes}\choice\end{checkboxes}\end{varwidth}}
\newcommand{\tablecorrectchoice}{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\begin{checkboxes}\CorrectChoice\ \end{checkboxes}\end{varwidth}}

\checkboxchar{$\Box$}
\checkedchar{$\blacksquare$}

\renewcommand{\checkboxeshook}{
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

    \question Answer the following question: \\
    \begin{tabular}{r|*3{c}}
        & Orange & Green & Aubergine \\ \hline
        Fruit & \tablechoice & \tablechoice & \tablechoice \\
        Vegetable & \tablechoice & \tablecorrectchoice & \tablechoice \\
        Colorname & \tablechoice & \tablechoice & \tablechoice \\
    \end{tabular}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, that looks exactly like solving my problems. Need some time now to play around and understand ;-)

Comment: @Marteen: Will do soon, there were issues not letting me find time for my latex stuff these days. Sorry...

Comment: Really, really sorry for my huge delay... I start to get the point of of what you're doing.
However, I can't build your full code (TeXLive-2014): test2.tex:22 Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (R): `c' used \begin{tabular}{R{1.7cm}|*3{C{2cm}}}
test2.tex:22 Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (1.7cm): `c' used \begin{tabular}{R{1.7cm}|*3{C{2cm}}}

Comment: @hoeni Don't worry about delays :) The reason why you couldn't compile was because there was  a typo in my code (a remnant from a previous edit). Anyway, it's fixed now. I also tried to give a better explanation as to why I do what I do. And I also added code for the correct choice checkbox to use in case you want to print solutions.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for your helpful explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Based on Maarten Dhondt's helpful answer I built myself an environment with the number of horizontal options to avoid repeating myself for other questions:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newenvironment {choicetable} [1] {
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
    \renewcommand{\checkboxeshook}{
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
    }
    \newcommand{\CO}{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\begin{checkboxes}\choice\end{checkboxes}\end{varwidth}}
    \newcommand{\CX}{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\begin{checkboxes}\CorrectChoice\ \end{checkboxes}\end{varwidth}}
    \begin{tabular}{r*{#1}{c}}
} {
    \end{tabular}   
}
\checkboxchar{$\Box$}
\checkedchar{$\blacksquare$}


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question Answer the following question: \\
    \begin{choicetable}{3}
        & Orange & Green & Aubergine \\ \hline
        Fruit & \CO & \CO & \CO \\
        Vegetable & \CO & \CX & \CO \\
        Colorname & \CO & \CO & \CO \\
    \end{choicetable} 
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[11p,twoside,a4paper,leqno]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, makecell, eqparbox}
\newcommand\tsq{$\square$}
\newcommand\colhead[2][black]{\eqmakebox[H][c]{\color{#1}{#2}}}
\setcellgapes{8pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \makegapedcells
  \begin{tabular}{@{}r! {\vrule width 0.8pt}*{3}{c}}%{>{\centering $}m{2cm}<{$}}
                & \colhead[DarkOrange3]{Orange} & \colhead[OliveDrab3]{Green} & \colhead[Plum4]{Aubergine} \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
    Fruit & \tsq & \tsq & \tsq \\
    Vegetable & \tsq & \tsq & \tsq \\
    Colour name & \tsq & \tsq & \tsq
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't see how this is useable as multiple choice questions for the exam class.
Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I didn't understand you want to use the `\choice` command. There was no code when I saw the question, and I didn't check before posting.