# Using \CorrectChoice (exam package) inside tabularx Environment

Tags: tabularx, exam

For modelling a list of questions with yes/no answers I wanted to define an environment where I can setup a question with a command: `\clO` for an option that's not applicable and `\clX` for those that are applicable.

Based on the solution in [How can I lay out multiple choice answers as a matrix with exam?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237069/how-can-i-lay-out-multiple-choice-answers-as-a-matrix-with-exam/237116#237116) I wanted to use `tabularx` instead of `tabular`, as the right column has to be multiline and fill up all the space.

Everything works as planned until I want to finally set one element as `\CorrectChoice` in the `\clO` or `\clX` command, resulting in a weird error message:
`mwe.tex:41 Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{choicelist}`

**MWE:**

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\checkboxchar{$\Box$}
\checkedchar{$\blacksquare$}

\newcommand{\clO}[1]{
    \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\begin{checkboxes}\CorrectChoice\end{checkboxes}\end{varwidth}
    & \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\begin{checkboxes}\choice\end{checkboxes}\end{varwidth}
    & #1\\
}
\newcommand{\clX}[1]{
    \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\begin{checkboxes}\choice\end{checkboxes}\end{varwidth}
    & \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\begin{checkboxes}\choice\end{checkboxes}\end{varwidth}
    & #1\\
}
\newenvironment{choicelist}{
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
    \renewcommand{\checkboxeshook}{
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
    }
  \tabularx{\textwidth}{ccX}
    applicable & not applicable & \\
}{
    \endtabularx
}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?

    \begin{choicelist}
        \clO{This is a multiline description to be answered, so we have to use a long text to ensure we can see a line break in the example.}
        \clX{foo}
        \clO{bar}
    \end{choicelist}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not a problem of `tabularx`: if I change `tabularx` to `tabular`, the problem is the same and is due to the fact that a group ends up straddling two alignment cells, which is not allowed.

Comment: What is meant by 'group' here? The command? or the start & end of the environment? 'alignment cells' are the table columns? Why does /CorrectChoice trigger that problem and /choice does not? How could I workaround this?

Comment: The command `\CorrectChoice` issues a `\begingroup` command`, whose matching `\endgroup` occurs much later, at `\end{checkboxes}`, which happens in another alignment cell; this is not allowed. The `\choice` command doesn't issue this `\begingroup` command.

Comment: I also tried putting both ends together in a command with no success.
So I really will have to paste those two checkboxes manually over and over again for each question?
(...but I'll start the long way of trying to understand what happens inside exam.cls :-))

Comment: @hoeni `\begin{checkboxes}\CorrectChoice\end{checkboxes}` should be `\begin{checkboxes}\CorrectChoice\ \end{checkboxes}`

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and redefined `\choice` and `\CorrectChoice`, so that I can use them inside a `tabular` environment and without adding `checkboxes` environment.

```
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\CorrectChoice}{% true
 \ifprintanswers
   $\boxtimes$%
 \else%
   $\square$%
 \fi%
 \xspace%
}
\newcommand{\choice}{% false
   $\square$%
   \xspace%
}
```